# how can i run a python code periodically on a docker container

Tags: python, docker, data-analysis

I have a python code which works for doing data analytics from csv file. I want to run my python code to be run periodically on a docker container. Every 15 seconds, it should automatically look at a folder A, if there is a csv file in it, it should process it and put an html report with the same name in folder B.

HERE IS MY PYTHON CODE .

```
#This program pulls data from csv file and displays it as html file.

#csv file contains device names, card names and temperatures of cards

#The html file contains: how many devices, how many cards are in the system, which 
#device has the highest temperature card, and in the table below is how many cards are 
#there in summary for each device, how many have a temperature of 70 and above, the 
#highest and average card what are the temperatures    
#NOTE: The print functions in the program are written for trial purposes.

from enum import unique
from re import A, T
import pandas as pd

from prettytable import PrettyTable, PLAIN_COLUMNS
table = PrettyTable() #create a table for device

table2 = PrettyTable() #create a table for summary

table.field_names = ["Device   -", "Total # of Cards  - ", "High Temp. Cards #  - ",         "Max Temperature - ", "Avg. Temperature   "]

table2.field_names = [" ","  "] 


df = pd.read_csv("cards.csv", sep=';', usecols = ['Device','Card','Temperature'])""", index_col=["Device","Card"]"""

print(type(df))
print(df["Device"].nunique(),"\n\n") # number of unique server

total_devices = df["Device"].nunique() # NUMBER OF DEVICES IN DIFFERENT TYPES
print(total_devices)


print(df["Device"].loc[1],"\n\n") 



print(df['Temperature'].max(),"\n\n") 
maxTemp = df['Temperature'].max() #finding max temperature
print("total card     ", )



i= 0
j=1

#Finding the card with the max temperature and the server where the card is located
while j > 0:
  if df["Temperature"].loc[i] == df["Temperature"].max():
   print(df["Device"].loc[i]) 
   print(df["Card"].loc[i])

   deviceName = df["Device"].loc[i]
   cardName = df["Card"].loc[i]
   j= 0 

  else :
   i = i+1 

dev_types = df["Device"].unique() # Server's names
print("\n\n")
newstr = cardName + "/" + deviceName
#Summary tablosunu olusturma
table2.add_row(["Total Devices         ", total_devices] )

table2.add_row(["Total Cads            ", len(df["Card"])])

table2.add_row(["Max Card Temperature  ", df["Temperature"].max()])



table2.add_row(["Hottest Card / Device " ,newstr])

print(table2)

row_num = len(df)
print(row_num)

#I pulled the data from the file according to the device type so that the server cards and temperatures were sorted, I found the max temp from here
dn = pd.read_csv("cards.csv", sep=';', index_col=["Device"], usecols = ['Device','Card','Temperature'])

sum = []
high = []


#print("max temp: ", dn["Temperature"].loc[dev_types[1]].max())
for x in range(total_devices): # total devices (according the file = 3 )
  print("\n")

  cardCount = 0 # counts the number of cards belonging to the device
  count2 = 0 # Counts the number of cards with a temperature greater than 70
  tempcount = 0
  print(dev_types[x])
  for y in range(row_num):
   if dev_types[x] == df["Device"].loc[y]:
     print(df["Temperature"].loc[y])
     tempcount = tempcount + df["Temperature"].loc[y]  # the sum of the temperatures of the cards(used when calculating the average)
     cardCount = cardCount +1 
     if df["Temperature"].loc[y] >= 70:
      count2 = count2 +1
  

  maxT = dn["Temperature"].loc[dev_types[x]].max() #Finding the ones with the max temperature from the cards belonging to the server
  avg = str(tempcount/cardCount)
  print("avg",avg)
  table.add_row([dev_types[x], cardCount, count2, maxT,avg ]) # I added the information to the "devices" table

  print("num of cards" , cardCount) 
  print("high temp cards" , count2)

print("\n\n")


print("\n\n")

print(table)

htmlCode = table.get_html_string()
htmlCode2 = table2.get_html_string()
f= open('devices.html', 'w') 
f.write("SUMMARY")
f.write(htmlCode2)
f.write("DEVICES")
f.write(htmlCode)
```

Comment: Well, have you tried an infinite loop with `time.sleep(15)` in it?

Comment: Maybe you can use [Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/). It would give you the opportunity to run tasks in whatever periods you want.

Comment: As an aside, your Pandas code seems very inefficient – you should practically never need to use a loop...

Comment: Note that "scan a directory" can be a little bit tricky in Docker.  Can you wrap this code in an HTTP server, maybe using Flask, and make an HTTP POST to do the processing rather than depend on having access to a shared directory?

Comment: @DavidMaze Can you elaborate on "a little bit tricky"?

Comment: Docker _by design_ normally prevents container processes from accessing host files.  So you need a special `docker run -v` option to grant that access, and then there are issues around filesystem permissions that need to get ironed out.  Shared directories also don't work well in clustered container environments (Docker Swarm, Kubernetes) if you're eventually going to migrate there.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not the code is run in Docker doesn't matter.

1. Wrap all of that current logic (well, not the imports and so on) in a function, say, `def process_cards()`.
2. Call that function forever, in a loop:

```
import logging


def process_cards():
    table = PrettyTable()
    ...

def main():
    logging.basicConfig()
    while True:
        try:
            process_cards()
        except Exception:
            logging.exception("Failed processing")
        time.sleep(15)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As an aside, your data processing code can be *vastly* simplified:

```
import pandas as pd

from prettytable import PrettyTable


def get_summary_table(df):
    summary_table = PrettyTable()  # create a table for summary
    total_devices = df["Device"].nunique()
    hottest_card = df.loc[df["Temperature"].idxmax()]
    hottest_device_desc = f"{hottest_card.Card}/{hottest_card.Device}"
    summary_table.add_row(["Total Devices", total_devices])
    summary_table.add_row(["Total Cards", len(df["Card"])])
    summary_table.add_row(["Max Card Temperature", df["Temperature"].max()])
    summary_table.add_row(["Hottest Card / Device ", hottest_device_desc])
    return summary_table


def get_devices_table(df):
    devices_table = PrettyTable(
        [
            "Device",
            "Total # of Cards",
            "High Temp. Cards #",
            "Max Temperature",
            "Avg. Temperature",
        ]
    )
    for device_name, group in df.groupby("Device"):
        count = len(group)
        avg_temp = group["Temperature"].mean()
        max_temp = group["Temperature"].max()
        high_count = group[group.Temperature >= 70]["Temperature"].count()
        print(f"{device_name=} {avg_temp=} {max_temp=} {high_count=}")
        devices_table.add_row([device_name, count, high_count, max_temp, avg_temp])
    return devices_table


def do_processing(csv_file="cards.csv", html_file="devices.html"):
    # df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, sep=';', usecols=['Device', 'Card', 'Temperature'])
    # (Just some random example data)
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        "Device": [f"Device {1 + x // 3}" for x in range(10)],
        "Card": [f"Card {x + 1}" for x in range(10)],
        "Temperature": [59.3, 77.2, 48.5, 60.1, 77.2, 61.1, 77.4, 65.8, 71.2, 60.3],
    })
    summary_table = get_summary_table(df)
    devices_table = get_devices_table(df)

    with open(html_file, "w") as f:
        f.write(
            "<style>table, th, td {border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;}</style>"
        )
        f.write("SUMMARY")
        f.write(summary_table.get_html_string(header=False))
        f.write("DEVICES")
        f.write(devices_table.get_html_string())


do_processing()
```

Answer (score 0):

i have an example of repeat decorator for run your function every seconds or minutes ...

i hope this sample helps you

```
from typing import Optional, Callable, Awaitable
import asyncio
from functools import wraps



def repeat_every(*, seconds: float, wait_first: bool = False)-> Callable:
    def decorator(function: Callable[[], Optional[Awaitable[None]]]):
        is_coroutine = asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(function)

        @wraps(function)
        async def wrapped():
            async def loop():
                if wait_first:
                    await asyncio.sleep(seconds)
                while True:
                    try:
                        if is_coroutine:
                            await function()
                        else:
                            await asyncio.run_in_threadpool(function)
                    except Exception as e:
                        raise e
                    await asyncio.sleep(seconds)

            asyncio.create_task(loop())

        return wrapped
    print("Repeat every working well.")
    return decorator


@repeat_every(seconds=2)
async def main():
    print(2*2)

try:
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
except RuntimeError: 
    loop = None
    
if loop and loop.is_running():
    print('Async event loop already running.')
    tsk = loop.create_task(main())
    tsk.add_done_callback(
        lambda t: print(f'Task done with result= {t.result()}'))
else:
    print('Starting new event loop')
    asyncio.run(main())
```

and there is an option that you can make an entrypoint which has cronjob

Comment: OP's original code doesn't use `asyncio`. Adding it in just for a loop doesn't seem like a great idea.

Comment: this is just a sample idea to trigger great idea